# Inference from Nash Equilibrium Violates Total Probability

Tags: probability, nash-equilibrium

This is connected to a question I asked at [Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/396407/bayesian-indecision).

Given a game:

```
          k
        x   y
    x: 1*,2|1*,1*
j
    y: 1*,1*|2,3
```

The best choices are marked with stars. Inference from the Nash Equilibrium tells me that $p(A_j=x)=\frac{2}{3}$, $p(A_k=y)=\frac{1}{2}$, and $p(A_k=y|A_j=x)=1$, where $A_i$ is the action of person $i$. However, this inference does not satisfy total probability because $$p(A_k=y) = \sum_x' p(A_k=y|A_j=x')p(A_j=x') \geq p(A_k=y|A_j=x)p(A_j=x)=\frac23.$$ Thus, I'm obviously inferring wrongly from the Nash Equilibrium. How can I correctly find the probabilities I wish to find given the Nash Equilibrium?

Comment: Are lower scores better in this game?  In any case, I have no idea how you found that $p(A_k=y|A_j=x)=1$: a Nash equilibrium will never tell you anything about conditional probabilities like that, since the two players make their choices independently (assuming they play simultaneously).

Comment: Lower scores are better, yes. I got the conditional probability by the Nash Equilibrium. When $A_j$ chooses $x$, there is only one instance in which $A_k$ makes a choice.

Comment: Does player $j$ move before player $k$, or do they play simultaneously?  If they play simultaneously, then player $k$'s choice can't depend on player $j$'s choice!  (And if player $j$ moves first, the analysis is totally different.)

Comment: Also, to be clear, $j$'s score is listed first?  So for instance, if both choose $x$, then $j$ scores $1$ and $k$ scores $2$?

Comment: I fail to see why the probability cannot be dependent. Maybe I mean to speak of likelihood rather than probability. I am trying to capture the fact that $k$'s best choice when $j$ chooses $x$ is definitely $y$.

And yes, $U_j(A_j=x|A_k=x)=1$ and $U_k(A_k=x|A_j=x)=2$.

Comment: "$k$'s best choice when $j$ chooses $x$ is definitely $y$" is true, but $k$ doesn't get to always make their best choice!  They don't know what $j$ is going to choose, and have to probabilistically make their move _before_ seeing $j$'s move.

Comment: So $p(BC_k=y|A_j=y)=1$. I don't know if that changes the problem with total probability. In the end, my goal is to use just the Nash Equilibrium to do Bayesian updating, that is why the conditional is so important.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be badly confused about the basic meaning of a game like this (or perhaps what a Nash equilibrium is).  Here's how it's played.  Player $j$ and player $k$ each secretly choose to move either $x$ and $y$ (and they may make this choice randomly).  Then they reveal their moves and receive payoffs according to the table.

So, what strategies are $j$ and $k$ allowed to use?  They don't have much flexibility, since they have to make their choices *before* they've seen the other player's move.  The only choice they have to make is the probability with which they choose each move.  So $j$ can choose to move $x$ with probability $p$, say (this is what you called $P(A_j=x)$), and $y$ with probability $1-p$.  Meanwhile, $k$ can choose to move $x$ with probability $q$ (what you called $P(A_k=x)$), and $y$ with probability $1-q$.  Crucially, these events $A_k=x$ and $A_j=x$ are *independent*, because $j$ and $k$ make their random choices without knowing the other player's move yet.  In particular, $P(A_k=y|A_j=x)$ must always be the same as $P(A_k=y)$.

Now, what is a Nash equilibrium?  It's a choice of strategies for each player (i.e., values of $p$ and $q$) such that neither player could do better (in expected value) by changing their strategy while the other player's strategy remains the same.  This game actually has infinitely many Nash equilibria.  To analyze it, let's start by looking from the perspective of $j$.  Note that $x$ is *always* a better move for $j$ than $y$, unless $k$ is always going to pick $x$ (i.e., $q=1$) in which case $j$'s choice does not matter.  This means that in any Nash equilibrium with $q\neq 1$, $p$ must be $1$ since moving $x$ is strictly better than moving $y$ for $j$.  If $j$ is moving $x$, then the best choice for $k$ is to move $y$.  This gives the first equilibrium $(p,q)=(1,0)$, where $j$ always moves $x$ and $k$ always moves $y$.

That's not the only Nash equilibrium, though, because we can only conclude that $p$ must be $1$ if $q\neq 1$.  If $q=1$, then $j$'s choice is irrelevant (for $j$) and so all strategies are equally good for $j$.  So, we can have a Nash equilibrium $(p,1)$ for any value of $p$ such that $k$'s best move is $x$, given that $j$ moves $x$ with probability $p$.  A bit of calculation shows that this is true as long as $p\leq 2/3$.  So for any $c\leq 2/3$, $(p,q)=(c,1)$ is also a Nash equilibrium.

Comment: "In particular, $P(Ak=y|Aj=x)$ must always be the same as $P(Ak=y)$" is helpful for me. Also, the way you break down Nash Equilibrium is what I've usually seen called "Mixed Strategy Nash Equilibrium." Is there a difference between the two beyond the introductory level? Also, can you recommend a text that combines the study of probability, its laws, and game theory?

Comment: I guess you can talk about Nash equiliibria where only pure strategies are allowed, but people rarely do so.  Note that this is really a difference in the rules of the game, not in the meaning of "Nash equilibrium": a pure strategy Nash equilibrium is a Nash equilibrium for the game where $j$ and $k$ are only allowed to use deterministic strategies (i.e., $p$ and $q$ can only be $0$ or $1$), while a mixed strategy Nash equilibrium is a Nash equilibrium for the game where they are allowed to use probabilistic strategies.

Comment: Can you recommend a text that combines the study of probability, its laws, and game theory?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a good reference.

Comment: I put up a bounty specifically for references, yet your answer gives no references.

"This question has an open bounty...

I expect an answer to the questions asked in the Cross-Validated Post as well as that one here. I would like citations that lead me to learn more about probability and game theory."

Comment: Is 50 rep just chump change to you? I expect a proper answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Any intermediate level microeconomics text will do the job. Moreover, game theory itself involves probability, and in some context (e.g. when you have incomplete information), you do consider Bayes-Nash equilibria. [Here](https://edisciplinas.usp.br/pluginfile.php/2963526/mod_resource/content/1/%288th%20Edition%29%20%28The%20Pearson%20Series%20in%20Economics%29%20Robert%20Pindyck%2C%20Daniel%20Rubinfeld-Microeconomics-Prentice%20Hall%20%282012%29.pdf) is what I used when I learned micro. [This](https://labs.xjtudlc.com/labs/wldmt1/books/Economics%20and%20game%20theory/Microeconomic%20Theory.pdf) text is more advanced.